# How to replace NVL function in a sql query

Tags: oracle, select, oracle-sqldeveloper, nvl

I need to replace an NVL function into a select

for example

`NVL (MAX(EX.ID_EXAMPLE),0)`

How can I replace this into my query

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the full query?

Comment: This one

SELECT COUNT (1) EXIST, NVL (MAX(EX.CD_ID_EXAMPLE),0) CD_ID_EXAMPLE FROM EXAMPLE EX WHERE EX.CD_ID_ = :cd_id

Comment: And what is wrong with using `NVL` as you currently have it?

Comment: A bad performance into data base server

Comment: The Database manager Suggest replace NVL function for another way to get a similar result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NVL (MAX(EX.ID_EXAMPLE),0)
```

can be replaced with `CASE..WHEN` as following:

```
CASE WHEN 
MAX(EX.ID_EXAMPLE) IS NOT NULL THEN 
MAX(EX.ID_EXAMPLE)
ELSE 0 
END
```

and better way is to use a subquery in which `MAX` is calculated and in outer query use alias in `CASE..WHEN` so that `MAX` is not calculated twice.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN
MAX_ID_EXAMPLE IS NULL THEN MAX_ID_EXAMPLE 
ELSE 0 
END
...
FROM (SELECT MAX(EX.ID_EXAMPLE) AS MAX_ID_EXAMPLE 
...
FROM ...)
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

The premise is wrong, changing `NVL` in a SQL statement like this won't improve performance:

```
SELECT COUNT (1) EXIST, NVL (MAX(EX.CD_ID_EXAMPLE),0) CD_ID_EXAMPLE
  FROM EXAMPLE EX
 WHERE EX.CD_ID_ = :cd_id;
```

Compared with retrieving the data, the time to process the data through `NVL` is irrelevantly small.  Oracle performance tuning is about how data is retrieved and joined.  The time for the CPU to process small functions almost never matters.  Especially in this example, where `NVL` will literally only run once for the entire statement.

(If the `NVL` was used as a condition, then things might be different.  There are times when `NVL`, or any function, can impact cardinality estimates, and thus affect the execution plans.  But not in your query.)

Another red flag is `COUNT(1)`, one of the oldest Oracle performance tuning myths.  I have a feeling you're at an organization with a lot of cargo cult programming.  In the long run, you need to build a culture that uses reproducible test cases, and start eliminating these myths.

Answer (score 1):

You may try adding the following index to your table:

```
CREATE TABLE idx ON EXAMPLE (CD_ID, CD_ID_EXAMPLE);
```

I don't even know whether adding `CD_ID_EXAMPLE` would even help, because you are doing a count over the entire table.  So, the following alone might be the best you can do here:

```
CREATE TABLE idx ON EXAMPLE (CD_ID);
```

This would at least help Oracle quickly remove records which do not match the `WHERE` clause.